# Не удаётся загрузить в переменную json файл со словарём

Tags: python, словари, dict

py файл и json файл лежат в одной папке. json файл содержит словарь.
Необходимо загрузить json файл(словарь) в переменную, чтобы проитерироваться по нему.

Делал так:

```
with open('test.json', 'r') as file:
   data = json.loads(file)
   print(data)
```

выпадает ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testtest.py", line 15, in <module>
    data = json.loads(file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    'not {!r}'.format(s.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'TextIOWrapper'
```

Comment: замените `json.loads` -> `json.load`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Передавайте не объект файла, а его данные, которые можно получить с помощью `file.read()`. Либо используйте [`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load).

***Примеры:***

```py
with open('test.json') as file:
    data = json.loads(file.read())
```

```py
with open('test.json') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
```